# Javascript - What is wrong with this function and loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, loops, for-loop

I started learning to code just a couple days ago, and I'm almost finished with my first program. However, I have ran into a problem now at the end, and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong myself.

The program is supposed to help me sort a bunch of dates by week day and time of day. The dates are written "YYMMDD-" and then the time of the day (only hour), e.g. "170109-06".

I have all the dates I want to sort in an array (*time*), and the following function and loop are supposed to delete all the dates that's not matching a specific year.

Variable clarification:

*time* - array consisting of dates and time (all the same months but different years. ( e.g. ["161102-03", "151127-11"]

yearDate - the first 4 numbers of the dates that's going to stay in the array.

```
function checkDate (date) {
    var yearMonth = date.slice(0, 4);
    var index = time.indexOf(date)
    if (yearMonth != yearDate) {
        time.splice(index, index + 1);
    } 
    else {
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i <= time.length; i++) {
    checkDate(time[i]);
}
```

This code seems to work occasionally, but sometimes a few strings from the array stay there when they're supposed to be deleted, so there's clearly something wrong with the code.

I hope that you'll be able to understand what I mean. I do realize that this post ended up kind of wooly.

Comment: have you tried to debug it yourself?

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Have you consulted your [Rubber Duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Answer (score 1):

Standard mistake. You are deleting items from array while iterating over it. Every time an item is deleted, incrementing the iterator will jump you over the next element, adjacent to the deleted.

Go backwards:

```
for (var i = time.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    checkDate(time[i]);
}
```